# How can I re-establish text threads after merging multiple files into one for ebook?

Tags: adobe-indesign, cs6, ebook

I have combined multiple CS6 Indesign files into one through the "move pages" option. Now, I need all my text links to be re-establish because this book will also be produced as ebook as well. Is that possible? If so, how do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Once two unconnected pages are in the same file, you can connect them the same way you have with the pages that were already there. Click the text thread square in the bottom-right of the page (just above the bottom-right corner) and then click on the frame you'd like to connect. Even if there's content in the imported frame, the two threads will connect. You might see your text reflow based on the amount of space in each side of the thread.